# Showing hamburger icon on a custom toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, hamburger-menu

I made a `NavigationView` and included `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`in my code to show the hamburger button, and it worked. but then i removed the default toolbar (by setting `AppTheme` in `styles` values to `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`), and implemented my own toolbar in the layout. And now instead of the Hamburger button, it shows the back button, although clicking on it draws the `NavigationView`. What should i do?

My Java code:

```
private DrawerLayout sideBar;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle sideBarToggle;
private Toolbar actionToolbar;

@Override
public void onCreate(...) {

    sideBar = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.sqliteLayout);
    sideBarToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, sideBar, actionToolbar, R.string.sideBarOpen, R.string.sideBarClose);
    actionToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.navAction);
    sideBar.addDrawerListener(sideBarToggle);
    sideBarToggle.syncState();
    setSupportActionBar(actionToolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(sideBarToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;}

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

My Toolbar code:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/navAction"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**SOLUTION:**

I reordered the java code to this, and removed the 3rd argument in `new ActionBarDrawerToggle(...)` and it worked!

```
    actionToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.navAction);
    setSupportActionBar(actionToolbar);
    sideBar = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.sqliteLayout);
    sideBarToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, sideBar,  R.string.sideBarOpen, R.string.sideBarClose);
    sideBar.addDrawerListener(sideBarToggle);
    sideBarToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setSupportActionBar(actionToolbar);` before you set up your `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

`ActionBarDrawerToggle` uses `getSupportActionBar()` under the hood, so all the work it is doing is wiped out when you call `setSupportActionBar` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added:

```
   actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Not this one:

getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(true);